# Flutter: ChangeNotifierProxyProvider: not providing updated correct state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-provider

I am trying to get state from one `ChangeNotifier` `Auth.dart` into another `ChangeNotifier` `ProductsProvider.dart`. But `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` is providing incorrect state data for `Auth`.

`main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(create: (ctx) => Auth()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ProductsProvider>(
            create: (context) => ProductsProvider(
              Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false),
              productList: [],
            ),
            update: (ctx, auth, preProducts) {
              print("ChangeNotifierProxyProvider Token ${auth.isAuth}");
              print("ChangeNotifierProxyProvider Token ${auth.token}");
              print("ChangeNotifierProxyProvider Test ${auth.test}");
              return ProductsProvider(
                auth,
                productList:
                    preProducts == null ? [] : preProducts.getProductList,
              );
            },
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Cart()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Order()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Auth()),
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Auth>(
      builder: (ctx, auth, _) {
        print("Builder Token ${auth.isAuth}");
        print("Builder Token ${auth.token}");
        print("Builder Test ${auth.test}");
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
            accentColor: Colors.orange,
            fontFamily: "Lato",
          ),
          routes: {
            "/": (ctx) => auth.isAuth ? ProductOverviewScreen() : AuthScreen(),
            ProductDetailScreen.PRODUCT_DETAIL_ROUTE: (ctx) =>
                ProductDetailScreen(),
            CartScreen.CART_SCREEN_ROUTE: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
            OrderScreen.ORDER_SCREEN_ROUTE: (ctx) => OrderScreen(),
            UserProductScreen.USER_PRODUCT_ROUTE: (ctx) => UserProductScreen(),
            EditProductScreen.EDIT_PRODUCT_ROUTE: (ctx) => EditProductScreen(),
          },
        );
      },
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

`Auth.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shop_app/models/HttpException.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  String _userId;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String test;

  bool get isAuth => token != null;

  String get token {
    if (_token == null
        // && _expiryDate != null &&
        // _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now())
        ) {
      return null;
    }
    return _token;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(String email, String password, String url) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);

    final response = await http.post(
      uri,
      body: jsonEncode({
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "returnSecureToken": true,
      }),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (responseData["error"] != null) {
      throw HttpException(responseData["error"]["message"]);
    }

    _token = responseData["idToken"];
    _userId = responseData["localId"];
    test = "_token";
    // _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
    //     .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData["expiresIn"])));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    const url =
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[KEY]";
    return await _authenticate(email, password, url);
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    const url =
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[KEY]";
    return await _authenticate(email, password, url);
  }
}
```

`ProductsProvider.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shop_app/models/HttpException.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/models/Product.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/providers/Auth.dart';

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _productList = [];

  Auth _auth;

  ProductsProvider(this._auth, {List<Product> productList = const []})
      : _productList = productList;

  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        "https://flutter-shop-app-3035a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products.json?auth=${_auth.token}");
    try {
      final response = await http.get(uri);
      if (response.body != "null") {
        final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJSON = jsonDecode(response.body);
        final List<Product> loadedProductList = [];

        decodedJSON.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
          loadedProductList.add(Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData["title"],
            description: prodData["description"],
            price: prodData["price"],
            imageUrl: prodData["imageUrl"],
            isFavourite: prodData["isFavourite"],
          ));
        });
        _productList = loadedProductList;
      } else {
        _productList = [];
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  List<Product> get getProductList {
    return _productList;
  }

  Product findById(String id) =>
      _productList.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        "https://flutter-shop-app-3035a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products.json");

    try {
      final responseProduct =
          await http.post(uri, body: jsonEncode(product.toJSon()));

      final finalProduct = Product(
          id: jsonDecode(responseProduct.body)["name"],
          title: product.title,
          description: product.description,
          price: product.price,
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl);

      _productList.add(finalProduct);
      notifyListeners();
      return Future.value();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateProduct(String id, Product product) async {
    var productIndex = _productList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    if (productIndex >= 0) {
      var uri = Uri.parse(
          "https://flutter-shop-app-3035a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products/$id.json");

      try {
        await http.patch(uri,
            body: jsonEncode({
              "title": product.title,
              "description": product.description,
              "price": product.price,
              "imageUrl": product.imageUrl,
              "isFavourite": product.isFavourite,
            }));

        _productList[productIndex] = product;
        notifyListeners();
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(String id) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(
        "https://flutter-shop-app-3035a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products/$id.json");

    final existingProductIndex =
        _productList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    var existingProduct = _productList[existingProductIndex];
    _productList.removeAt(existingProductIndex);
    final response = await http.delete(uri);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      _productList.insert(existingProductIndex, existingProduct);
      notifyListeners();

      throw HttpException("Could not delete product");
    }
    existingProduct = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

After I click the login button the login method from the `Auth.dart` is trigged. After fetching the token the from firebase the screen is updated to `ProductOverviewScreen`. But the `ProductsProvider.dart` is not able to fetch the items because the `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` update is returning an incorrect state for Auth.

Output:

```
Builder Token true
Builder Token eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNkOWNmYWE4OGVmMDViNDI0YmU2MjA1ZjQ2YjE4OGQ3MzI1N2JjNDIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmx1dHRlci1zaG9wLWFwcC0zMDM1YSIsImF1ZCI6ImZsdXR0ZXItc2hvcC1hcHAtMzAzNWEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MjE3NzUxMDYsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJ5Y0dVVWhwYTFvY2EwMThlYUx4VGZkQnRNbmsyIiwic3ViIjoieWNHVVVocGExb2NhMDE4ZWFMeFRmZEJ0TW5rMiIsImlhdCI6MTYyMTc3NTEwNiwiZXhwIjoxNjIxNzc4NzA2LCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAdGVzdC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImZpcmViYXNlIjp7ImlkZW50aXRpZXMiOnsiZW1haWwiOlsidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBhc3N3b3JkIn19.t1xosbzllt79NV6FQ79mTQ2J3VCR5fILKMxE5-ObOxMI2DtD_kMg2AP9NXm_f1IsLF9AT5xeXeVU36goVDLQuKSWmbejOANDn7hsF6VzZMyBV1P9qehXpWgSmCscjXT8FRlKViZzxOZwCWSHS1M94n92YYhwaZltiDcQ87hhv7ZdKyLrlDsUPfr7IjNBeSVDmzws_9uBoZwYKRYCW1veWPc7HPWtdP8QT7K_vkCEvGLHfxbmVHOgUkDMzLqhgusZl34GCPVKr_PSpQ9SgC7Mg95QeZyzYzPmhasGUptq5pQsjEoqTxgYHnmEuMRRjksZT5lbfsQQFOJMsXBTIC7RDQ
Builder Test _token
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider Token false
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider Token null
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider Test null
Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:5333:11)
    at ProductProvider.ProductsProvider.new.fetchAndSetProducts (http://localhost:1344/packages/shop_app/providers/ProductProvider.dart.lib.js:84:21)
    at fetchAndSetProducts.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:39031:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:38888:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:33874:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:34434:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:34472:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:34314:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:34337:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:39175:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:39181:13)
    at http://localhost:1344/dart_sdk.js:34688:9
```

I am learning dart and flutter. I am not sure what I am missing. Can someone could help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find what was causing this issue.
It appears I was reinitializing the `Auth` ChangeNotifierProvider. If you see the last line in the `MultiProvider` constructor providers argument.

If anyone else comes across such an issue ensure that you have specified the providers in the correct order.

Comment: It would be better if you add the code with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Product Id defined int/Integer, but the parser from firebase is String. You need change in Product Id to String or use int.parse(prodId)